# Why is my correct answer in the same place in each loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is a basic maths quiz where my correct answer is inserted into a list which is my answer options for each question. For each new question my correct answer is in the same place but I want it in a different place each time. Here's my code:

```
from random import randint
quiz_options=[["What is 1+1?", "2",["1","3","4","5"]],
          ["What is 5+10?", "15",["12","34","42","25"]],
          ["What is 16*2?", "32",["69","34","38","72"]],
          ["What is 10/5?", "2",["15","7","10","5"]]]

randomo=randint(0,5)
w=0
for question in quiz_options:
    quiz_options[w][2].insert(randomo,quiz_options[w][1])
    print (quiz_options[w][0])
    n=1
    for choice in quiz_options[w][2]:
         print(n ,") -", choice)
         n=n+1
    user_choice= int(input("Your answer: "))
    if user_choice == quiz_options[w][2].index(quiz_options[w][1])+1:
         print("correct")
    else:
         print("incorrect")
    w=w+1
```

Here an example:

```
What is 1+1?
1 ) - 2
2 ) - 1
3 ) - 3
4 ) - 4
5 ) - 5
Your answer: 1
correct
What is 5+10?
1 ) - 15
2 ) - 12
3 ) - 34
4 ) - 42
5 ) - 25
Your answer: 1
correct
```

See how the answer is in the same place? How would I make it so it's in a different place each time?

Comment: you are generating `randomo` only once. Move the line `randomo = randint(0, 5)` inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you generate the random position once and use it for all questions.

```
randomo=randint(0,5)
```

move this line inside the for loop, then you will have a new random position for each question.